# Dont know how to solve DBQuery fatal error

Tags: php

Hey stackoverflow community, I've got question, I'm getting this error:

> **Fatal error**:  Class 'DBQuery' not found in

And, if I know that this class is written in query.class.php file. How can i fix this error? I've never done this before, so I thought you guys could help me? This is what am i trying to do:

```
$q = new DBQuery;
$q->addQuery("ut.user_id, perc_assignment, concat_ws(', ', contact_last_name, contact_first_name) as contact_name");
$q->addTable('user_tasks', 'ut');
$q->leftJoin('users', 'u', array('user_id'));
$q->leftJoin('contacts', 'c', 'c.contact_id = u.user_contact');
$q->addWhere('task_id ='.$task_id.' AND task_id <> 0');
$assigned_perc = db_loadHashList($q->prepare(true), 'user_id');
```

So should i use:

```
require('query.class.php');
```

Or something?

Comment: Where is your code???

Comment: Nobody here can help with code you're not showing us, we can't see your screen from here.

Comment: I updated. I just need to know how to call the file so that my code could use that class

Comment: you just need specify the whole path to the file. require('query.class.php'); this code tells me that the query.class.php in the same directory as your calling script

Comment: @volkinc not in the same, its just for example. :)

Comment: so just specify  the right path to the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have defined `class DBQuery` in your `query.class.php` file then yes, include that file before using it. If you dont, then declare that class before using it

Comment: My folder is in root/module/tasks/ajax/file and class is in root/class/file and i get error that not found such a file :/ i was using `require_once DP_BASE_DIR . '/classes/query.class.php';`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not include your Class file, obviously when you try to instantiate that class it will fail with the above error. require (/path/to/class.php); will probably do the job in your case!

Comment: My folder is in root/module/tasks/ajax/file and class is in root/class/file and i get error that not found such a file :/ i was using `require_once DP_BASE_DIR . '/classes/query.class.php';`

Comment: `../../../class/query.class.php`

Comment: check what is in DP_BASE_DIR, and either use absolute path to your class file starting from the root folder of your installation, or use relative path .... really, we don't know your folder hirarchy, nor can we guess it! :)